# validation_inclusion_of rspec test case is returning ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6.1, shoulda-matchers

Let's consider a class with definition as shared below:

```
# a_type :string
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
    enum a_type: { fir: 'first', sec: 'second' }
    validates :a_type, presence: true, inclusion: { in: a_types.keys }
end
```

Rspec:

```
describe 'Validations' do
    it { is_expected.to validate_presence_of(:a_type) }
    it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:a_type).in_array(Foo.a_types.keys) }
end
```

Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to validate_inclusion_of(:a_type).in_array(Foo.a_types.keys) }

ArgumentError:
'shoulda-matchers test string' is not a valid a_type

Is this the expected behavior for this? Please help

I did try to explore ValidateInclusionOfMatcher from shoulda-matcher repo but couldn't find anything concrete.

It is not very clear why would validate inclusion fail and how does it check based on subject first and then apply ARBITRARY_OUTSIDE_STRING which results in above error.

My understanding is that it should check above behavior, one with value passed in subject using factorybot and other by replacing a_type to some random value.

Comment: Does this help? https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/issues/1433

Comment: I think it doesn't like your enum. Seems they [fixed it for polymorphic associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/pull/1523/files) but maybe not for enums. Do you need inclusion validation on an enum? Check if enums already enforce that.

Comment: Thanks, Good point, I will check if an inclusion check is needed when an enum is used for a column.
I also check the issue and PR you mentioned before but as you said it is for fixing polymorphic association

Answer (score 1):

Could you try changing the column name to something else? The name `type` is reserved for [STI](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html), or if you want to keep it, try overwriting the inheritance column:

```
self.inheritance_column = nil
```

That being said, `shoulda-matchers` error message is really confusing.

Comment: Type is more of an example, you can assume it as type1

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to validate or explicitly check for inclusion as an enum defined for a column does that implicitly.

Thanks @Schwern for pointing it out